# Error when writing drools rules in a string buffer

Tags: java, drools

I am setting up the drools rules using string buffer in which rules will build from db data. Below is my code snippet to prepare the rules in a string buffer.

```
    List<DbRules> dbRuleList = getAllRules();   
    KieSession kieSession = null;
    StringBuffer ruleBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    ruleBuffer.append("import com.model.ContractHeader; import static com.service.SupplierService.isRuleAppliesToSupplier;  ");
    for(DbRules rule : dbRuleList) {
        ruleBuffer.append(" rule \""+rule.getRuleName()+"\" when  eval( isRuleAppliesToSupplier( cHeader : ContractHeader (supplierName) , "+rule.getRuleId()+" )) && ("+rule.getLhs()+") then "+rule.getRhs()+" end; ");
    }
```

I am getting below exception in console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get 
KieModule, Errors Existed: Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, 
line=1, column=0
text=Rule Compilation error cHeader cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator
supplierName cannot be resolved to a variable]
```

---

### Warning Messages:

Info Messages:

```
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:453)
at com.sample.StringDrools.executeRules(StringDrools.java:88)
at com.sample.StringDrools.main(StringDrools.java:41)
```

Comment: `Rule Compilation error cHeader cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error is resolved by doing some code modification. Thanks!

```
  for(DbRules rule : dbRuleList) {
        ruleBuffer.append(" rule \""+rule.getRuleName()+"\" when cHeader:ContractHeader()  eval( isRuleAppliesToSupplier(  (cHeader.getSupplierName()) , "+rule.getRuleId()+" )) && ("+rule.getLhs()+") then "+rule.getRhs()+" end; ");
    }
```